# Viewing / Editing A Multisite website after domain has expired

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I'm using Wordpress MU Domain Mapping.

I've attempted to do a network update today, but one of the sites failed in the process ( and most likely stopped all others from updating ). The site in question's domain has expired recently. We let it expire because it wasn't generating any income, but we still wanted to keep the content.

Well now I have no idea how to access that content without the domain name. topleveldomain.com/domaininquestion doesnt work, Its probably a config issue. Any idea how to "remove" the expired domain from the site and access it in a topleveldomain.com/domaininquestion/wp-admin/ kind of way? The network is setup to use folders not subdomains.

And for example, lets say I add a new site to the multisite, and do not domain map it, I can access it like this topleveldomain.com/websitewithoutdomain/wp-admin, so I guess my question is, how do I reverse this process and "remove" the domain mapping?

I'm a huge noob at this, so please let me know if you have any questions to help clarify. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer...

All I did was went into the wordpress database for the main domain. And found the "wp_domain_mapping" table.

I then simply deleted the domain from the table. Now the url works with the main domain.

Yesss.